# How to prevent subscribe to service twice from foreach

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My service is saving twice when call inside foreach.

I have a service to upload file.

```
fileUpload(file: File, body: string) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("body", body);
        formData.append('file', file);

        return this.http.post<FileUpload>(environment.apiUrl + "/upload", formData);

    }
```

Then i have a method for upload

```
onFileSubmit() {
    Array.from(this.uploadFile).forEach(file => {
      this.taskService.fileUpload(file, JSON.stringify(this.arr))
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("payload", data);
          })
    });
  }
```

This is the sample uploadFile

[image]

And in my Postman this the way I am saving.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it to be called twice? You want to save each file right?

Comment: yes i want to save each file. But it happens that it is saving each file twice.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `this.uploadFile`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically `this.taskService.fileUpload(file, JSON.stringify(this.arr))` is an observable you could simply assign this to a variable and check whether this observable exist or not before making the api call.

```
myObservable;

onFileSubmit() {
    Array.from(this.uploadFile).forEach(file => {
      if(!this.myObservable) {
          this.myObservable = this.taskService.fileUpload(file, JSON.stringify(this.arr));
          this.myObservable.subscribe(data => {
            console.log("payload", data);
          })
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I tried this upload But the problem is when i upload multiple files it is only one that is being uploaded.

Comment: @raf surely yes. beacuse you have blocked the second file apload as of now. So my question is why do you want to prevent subscibing a service twice? How do you want this to be happened?

Comment: Because in database it is saving twice also.

Comment: For some clarifications. Is `this.uploadFile` an array with distinct objects? You mentioned that your code was creating duplicate records. If the `this.uploadFile` consists of 2 objects, then what is the entries created in db? Is it two records of `this.uploadFile[0]` , or two records of `this.uploadFile[1]`  or 4 records of `this.uploadFile[0]` x 2 and `this.uploadFile[1]` x 2?

Comment: Basically this.uploadFile has 2 objects. and the this.arr consist of 2 string array ojbect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to upload one file you can use the first (0th) file in this.uploadFile:

```
    onFileSubmit() {
       this.taskService.fileUpload(this.uploadFile[0], JSON.stringify(this.arr))
          .subscribe(data => { 
             console.log("payload", data);
          })
     });
    }
```

That should avoid multiple service calls.

Comment: Same with the answer above when I upload multiple files it is only uploading one file.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Array.from(this.uploadFile)` return an array of four elements.

Your intention is to iterate of the object. Another way is to get each file from the object:

```
`
    Object.keys(this.uploadFile).forEach((key) {
        this.taskService.fileUpload(this.uploadFile[key], JSON.stringify(this.arr))
            .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("payload", data);
      })
    });
`
```